# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/mypro/images/login/mypic.jpg] in DispatcherServlet with name 'myproject'

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, web, web-applications

I have implemented a simple spring MVC application and the page is not displaying the images and JS.

My code snippet. And I execute the program mvn clean install tomcat7:run

```
<!-- web.xml -->
<servlet>
<servlet-name>myproject</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet- class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>myproject</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/myproject-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

myproject-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="com.personnal.myproj.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>



<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" >
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

pom.xml

```
<build>
   <finalName>myproject</finalName>
   <plugins>

    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

       <!-- Config: Maven Tomcat Plugin -->

       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
           <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.2</version>
           <configuration>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
                <warName>myproject</warName>
            </configuration>
       </plugin>
   </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>3.8.1</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.36</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.18.2-GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-static-resources

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the link. I was searching all the way around in google, couldn't find any link. Now it works!!!!!